# Read bytes from string in Python

Tags: python, string, byte

I have a python string representing bytes read from network, I need to read successively several bytes from this string. For example I have 9 bytes in a string, I need to read 4 bytes as integer, 2 bytes as short, and 3 bytes of custom data type.

Is there a reader in python to do something like:

```
reader = reader(my_string)    

integer = int.from_bytes(reader.read(4), 'big')
short = int.from_bytes(reader.read(2), 'big')
custom = customType.Unpack(reader.read(3))
```

I thought use struct.unpack, but I don't know how to handle non-primitive types.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, what is your custom, non-primitive type, exactly?

Comment: It's a representation of another datas, as primitive types, and only this custom type know how to unpack it. Maybe that in my example, the custom type is 1 byte and 1 short.

Comment: I don't understand.  You're saying you have the code which knows how to unpack it, and you want us to tell you how to unpack it, without the code you have to unpack it?

Comment: The struct module is tailor made for this.

Comment: What I want is to extract datas from string representing bytes. I have the code to unpack everything but I need a reader to read N bytes for each types.

If I send the reader to my custom class I want it to be able to read from the current position in the string.

For example : I read 4 bytes, and give the reader to another class wich will read N bytes, and then give it to another class wich will read X more bytes etc ...

Comment: With the struct module I will need to update an offset each time I will read something and send this offset to the custom class, so that it can knows where to start its read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want this:

```
import struct
integer, short = struct.unpack('>ih', my_string)
custom = customType.Unpack(my_string[6:9])
```

Or maybe this:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
reader = StringIO(my_string)
integer, short = struct.unpack('>ih', reader.read(6))
custom = customType.Unpack(reader.read(3))
```

Comment: Read the section struct and then `import struct`